# How does Inverse QFT work in Quantum Phase Estimation?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-fourier-transform, quantum-phase-estimation, phase-kickback

I'm trying to implement Quantum Phase Estimation from [qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-phase-estimation.html).

Below is the implementation circuit taken from the above-mentioned site:

[image]

The output at position 2 will be as follows:

$$|\psi _2⟩ = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}} \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n}-1} e^{2\pi i k} |k⟩ ⊗ |\psi⟩ $$

and after applying inverse QFT, the state becomes:

$$ | \psi _3⟩ = \frac{1}{2^{n}} \sum_{x=0}^{2^{n}-1} \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n}-1} e^{- \frac{2 \pi i k}{2^{n}}(x-2^n \theta)} |x⟩ ⊗| \psi⟩ $$

However, the next step claims that the above expression peaks near $ x = 2^n \theta $ which is my point of doubt, why is this the case? Wouldn't the maximum amplitude be when $ x = 0 $ based on simple calculus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you obtain after applying the QFT contains sums of the unit square, $e^{2\pi i/2^n}$, which sum up to 0 if you sum over the full range of $2^n$:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} e^{\frac{2\pi i}{2^n} k} = 0
$$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891875/proof-that-sum-of-complex-unit-roots-is-zero) for explanations why this is the case.

Now the inner sum in the amplitudes will also sum up to 0, if $(x - 2^n\theta)$ is an integer, because that's just multiplication with a constant factor and the sum-to-zero-rule still holds.

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{2^n - 1} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} e^{\frac{2\pi i}{2^n} k (x - 2^n \theta)}
$$

**But:** If $(x - 2^n \theta) = 0$, then the exponential will be $e^0 = 1$ and your sum is collapsing to

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{2^n - 1} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} 1
$$

Therefore, the amplitudes are 0 if $x \neq 2^n \theta$ and 1 if $x = 2^n \theta$. 
Note that the derivation is more complicated if $2^n\theta$ is not an integer.

The QFT and its derivation is also very well explained in [Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), chapter 5.1, page 217, I would recommend to look up there if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer and the useful resource, it indeed cleared up my doubts!